Flutter web app not running and stuck at connecting the debug service to Chrome
Unable to run my flutter web app through android studio. It is stuck at
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...

Updated flutter, dart sdk. What can I do to solve this issue?
EDIT: tried creating another project and ran it without changing anything. Still won't run.

Have you tried restarting android studio, or restarting your PC? Sometimes a simple restart is all that's necessary

tried restarting both, doesn't work. Updated android studio today as well
